# Check specific axis with quaternions

Tags: object, unity-game-engine, 3d, rotation, quaternions

If I use euler angles, I'm aware of them having different ways to represent the same rotation but, at the same time, I need to be able to check the rotation progress in X axis. It starts, for instance, at rotation 15 degrees in X axis and I don't care about Y and Z. If I look at it after some movements of that object, maybe it shows that X axis is different although maybe X axis didn't move at all, this is because of euler angles. With quaternions this is not supposed to happen but I don't know how to check then, the progress in the rotation of one axis.

Comment: That's the nature of rotations - they are non-commutative so the order of operations matters. Therefore you can't define a unique "angle" for every axis because this depends on the order of XYZ rotations in whichever Euler angle convention you choose.

Comment: (As an aside, Octonions--8 value structures representing rotations in 4D space--are *non-associative* when multiplied. That is, like subtraction: `(2-3)-4 != 2-(3-4)` and unlike addition `(2+3)+4 == 2+(3+4)` which Quaternions are. Sedenions--16 value--get even *weirder* in that they are not even Alternative, and I don't even know what that means. People wonder why higher order math is complicated and confusing.)